# @JoinColumn and how it links two tables

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I am completely new to working with databases and a beginner to Spring Boot as well really so apologies for any wrong terminology/fuzzy logic. There are some similar questions to this on here but I have not found exactly the answer to what I was looking for so I decided to post. Ramble over.

I am reading an [article](https://ankitkamboj18.medium.com/a-guide-to-jpa-with-hibernate-relationship-mappings-onetoone-onetomany-manytoone-310ce31df3f6) about joining tables in Spring Boot. They have a teacher class and a course class and it is a one-to-many relationship. They don't have the full classes written out but it says that you can go into Teacher class and do:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "TEACHER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
private List<Course> courses;
```

or go to Course class and do:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "TEACHER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
private Teacher teacher;
```

What threw me off is that the parameters given to JoinColumn were the same in both cases. Assuming that both tables have something called ID, how does Spring know which one to use? Does it start by looking at both tables, looking for teacher_id. Then, after finding that it switches to the other table to get the ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is in the methodology of One-To-Many mappings in relational databases.
To achieve 1-N relation you only need to have:

```
Table One -> primary_key
Table Many -> primary_key, fk_one_primary_key
```

With the above configuration, given a table `One` entity, you can get all it's `Many` relations using the primaryKey-foreignKey join, and vice versa.

Now, in the code you've shared, the two parameters are described as:
`ID` -> Primary key column of table `One` / `Teacher`
`TEACHED_ID` -> foreign key column of table `Many` / `Course`

Comment: Thank you! So Spring knows that the foreign key will always be in the Many side of the relation?

Comment: Yes, that's implicit. Other frameworks/languages will do the same